# ccexp.Webview in quick-cocos2d-x 3.3

Tags: webview, lua, cocos2d-iphone

I used ccexp.Webview to show a web page in a dialog in app. I've tried add some other node to cover the webview. It seems that the webview is always shown with the highest zOrder, which means no Node can cover the Webview. And the webview will swallow the touch event.

So I wonder, is it possible to use a node to cover the Webview?